# Spring Boot Angular application route from spring controller to angular component(view)

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My application is a spring boot and angular 5 with angular as dependency added into spring boot app, Packaging is like

Backend Jar:

[image]

The angular app jar in in BackendJar\BOOT-INF\lib\angularapp.jar

The application loads the home page on load home(/) no problem here
but here I have a scenario where I need to navigate to home (/) when some condition is met in controller, like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
   if(request.getHeader("USER")=="something") {
      return "home"; //return Home page
   } else {
      return "error"; //error page here
   }
}
```

But spring throws a 404 when I try to navigate to home from controller like above. If I remove the `@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)`
it happily loads the home component.

What am I doing wrong here:

Do I need to give the exactly html name here or do I need to give the name in the router.
`{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}` or `home.component.html`

Comment: you can try this http://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward

Comment: it is not working. Is this because of the packaging, since I packaged all angular into a jar and including it as part of springboot jar. ? @georgesvan

Comment: please check, whether this might help you: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/url-to-view-mapping.html

Comment: @juniorDeveloper folow this course. you 'll learn everyting about Angula 4 and spring boot: https://www.udemy.com/angular-4-java-developers/learn/v4/content